# python definir un diccionario a partir de una columna de un tabla csv

Tags: python

A partir de un fichero csv, y de una columna, como definir una función para extraer datos de la columna y crear un diccionario
Como realizar los filtros para extraer la información de la columna que tiene número y letras.

Comment: No creo que a tu profesor le guste encontrar su pregunta en SO, y menos aún con respuestas ya hechas, no te parece?? Prueba a leer [ask], haz el [tour] y luego abres tu IDE de python e ***intentas hacer algo***. Si no sabes por donde empezar, google tiene varias recomendaciones al respecto si buscas "python csv", eso si, no te dan el código hecho para que copies y pegues tal como hariamos aquí, pero así ***aprendes*** a hacerlo tú, que para eso son los ejercicios. Si te atascas y tienes ***un error concreto***, seguro que podemos ayudarte con eso :)

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes un fichero csv como el siguiente, sin header

```
1
q
s
d
f
```

con este codigo funcionaria

```
with open("app/fichero.csv",'r') as fichero_csv:
    diccionario=dict()
    for column_n,linea in enumerate(fichero_csv):
        diccionario[column_n]=linea.strip()
```

un diccionario es conformado por dos elementos, llave:valor, la ejecucion del codigo produce

```
{0: '1', 1: 'q', 2: 's', 3: 'd', 4: 'f'}
```